# While trying to upload the build to testflight getting GET apps: 500 {"errors"=>[{"status"=>"500", "code"=>"UNEXPECTED_ERROR", "

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, fastlane

I am trying to uploade the build to testflight. I am facing the issue as below

> GET apps: 500 {"errors"=>[{"status"=>"500",
> "code"=>"UNEXPECTED_ERROR", "title"=>"An unexpected error occurred.",
> "detail"=>"An unexpected error occurred on the server side. If this
> issue continues, contact us at
> https://developer.apple.com/contact/."}]}

Alos if I try to manual upload it shows the below error
[image]